# Checking if a home backup is succesful

Tags: backup, hard-disk

I have make a copy of my home directory with

```
dd if=/dev/sda4 |pv|dd  of=/dev/sdb1
```

Now I want to enter to  my external drive. I tried

```
 sudo mount -vfat /dev/sdb1 /mnt/usbstick/
[sudo] password for user: 
/                        : ignored
/boot                    : ignored
/home                    : ignored
none                     : ignored
```

First time I do this, why this command is not enough to mount the media drive, so that I can access it later and browse the files?

Comment: Do you mean `mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /mnt/usbstick`? And are you sure that the filesystem type *is* vfat?

Comment: Why do an image copy with `dd`?   use `cp` or `rsync` or `tar` or any of dozens of other programs to do a file backup.   That will allow you to verify the copied files afterwards.  File copies are also much faster because they don't waste time and disk space copying all the unused/empty sectors of a disk.  Easier to restore too, you don't need a disk or partition of the same size, and you can restore individual files easily.

Comment: Are the partitions of the same type? You're copying raw partition data, so that's important to be able to mount it afterwards. Also, just use a filesystem level program to do this, and save yourself a whole heap of trouble.

Comment: @cas I have problems with `rsync`, suddenly it stops copying all the data, and there are no warning messages. I would appreciate so much if you can provide a hint of what is wrong. I type: `sudo rsync -rltzuv --inplace /home/jivifair/grim-reaper2/ .` and after some time it stops in some file `lap/proyecto-doc/BEGE/BEGOE_2/transition-dens/spectra0-250_n1023GOE/fort_1023.M0110.070.r0467`

Comment: @Nick and @l0b0 this is my first time using  `dd`, ignorant question: do I need to format first my external drive to match the filesystem of the /home? And also, do I need to create a partition of the same size in the external drive?

Comment: what do you mean "suddenly stops copying all the data"?  does rsync exit?  does it just pause forever? can you kill it with Ctrl-C?  Is there an error message?  Are there any error messages in the kernel log or in dmesg output?  Is it the same file every time?  This sounds a lot like a near-dying drive locking up under heavy load....and that's one of the things rsync is good for - reset the drive, let it cool down, then run the same rsync again so that it starts copying from where it left off last time.

Comment: Yes, the program just stops forever, and it alwalys stops in a very big file (doesn't have to be the same). I was thinking about it, and I also think that somehow moving a large amount of data makes the process not to terminate. I will try to copy my data by parts.